# Have problems with javascript and ajax sending mail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem with sending my email via webpage. It seems as if ajax never uses the data and sends it through..I got it to work somehow a while back, but didnt look at it ever since and i noticed it stoped working for some reason..

This is the contact form

HTML:

```
<div class="desni_meni_box_wrapper">
            <h2 class="sidebar">Postavite pitanje<h2> 
            <div class="desni_meni_box">
                <form class="ajaxform1" id="form1" method="post" action="skripte/pitanje.php">

                    <p class="I">
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Ime" id="name" required/>
                    </p>

                    <p class="email">
                        <input name="email" type="email" class="feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
                    </p>

                    <p class="text">
                        <textarea name="text" type="text" class="feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Postavite pitanje" required></textarea>
                    </p>


            <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="POŠALJI" class="button-blue" name="posalji2"/>
            <div class="ease"></div>
            </div>
            </form>
    </div>           
</div>
```

php of the form

PHP:

```
<?php
$recipient="myemailaddress@gmail.com";
$subject="Postavite Pitanje";
$sender1=$_POST["name"];
$senderEmail=$_POST["email"];
$poruka=$_POST["text"];

$mailBody=" Ime: $sender1\n Email: $senderEmail\n\n\n $poruka";

mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From:<$senderEmail>");
echo("ok");
?>
```

and the way i use ajax

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#form1').validate({


    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        comment: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 200
        },
    },
    errorPlacement: function() {
        return false;
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'skripte/pitanje.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: $(form).serialize(),

            success: function( data ) {
                alert('Poruka je poslana!');
                $('#form1').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Niste ispunili sva potrebna polja!');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});


});
```

I always get the  error: function as a result and cant get it to work...any ideas?

Comment: *Stopped working for some reason?*

Comment: It worked at one point, and i think i accidently changed some of the code while editing. But since i made the contact form with more pieces of code i found i cant remember (logicly speaking) how the whole process is suppose to go or what is wrong.

Comment: Do you have version control? Can you roll back to the version that worked? What is the *actual* error you get?

Comment: I just get the alert from the error: function()  back..
I cant roll back to the version that worked..i started keeping backups a month ago

Comment: Darn, that's not going to be of much use. You need to return the *actual* error. Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to find out how to do that.

Comment: I have been trying but im not sure what to do, i didnt work with php or javascrip much so i am having difficulty figuring out how to get the error..or some kind of log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems everything related to code was good. The host changed incoming and outgoing servers and didnt send any information on doing so.

Answer (score 0):

if you get error seems that the info is not sent to the right URL.

Please try `url:'/skripte/pitanje.php'`

Otherwise: please write var_dump($_POST) in your php file and
add $res in your `error: function($res) {console.log($res);}`

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)